# 404 error when making SOSL queries from native mobile applications

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, sosl, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am developing a native android app using the mobile sdk. I am trying to make a search query like this

```
RestRequest req = RestRequest.getRequestForSearch("v20.0", "FIND {"+searchString+"*} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Task(Id,Name)");
```

the problem is that I get

> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected Response Code 400 for
>   https://eu3.salesforce.com/services/v20.0/search? ....

Comment: EU3 was reporting problems this morning on trust.salesforce.com. Perhaps you are experiencing a knock on effect from those difficulties: http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status/

Comment: https://eu3.salesforce.com/services/v20.0/search? is the wrong URL it should be https://eu3.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/search? you should check exactly how RestRequest is building that url.

Answer (score 3):

When experiencing errors that are clearly raised from the server side, a good place to start is the [system status page at trust.salesforce.com](http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status/). At the time you seem to be accessing it, there appear to be some problems for the instance you are hitting. If you are new, your instance is in your URL:

```
https://eu3.salesforce.com/services/v20.0/search
         ^                           ^--------------version
         ^----------------instance
```

An additional point of advice (and probably not related to the error) is that you appear to be developing a new app on a very old version of the API (version 20). At the time of writing this, the current API version is 31. There have been significant improvements to the API, especially the REST API endpoints that you will want to leverage for your mobile app. If this is, in fact, a new app, I would strongly suggest developing against the current version. If it is an existing one, you might want to plan a time in your project soon to refactor your code to use the new API version.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I moved to version 31 but I am still experiencing the same issue. Are you sure is not related to the query itself?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the 400 Bad Request happen in the following cases as well so I'd strongly advise you check these

A) Are you encoding the request while sending it from your app
B) Check if the Auth header is properly set for your request

For example

```
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
```

Comment: Req object does not have the setHeader method